# Node.js : How to embed Node.js into HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, markup

**In a php file I can do:**

```
<p><?php echo "hello!";?></p>
```

Is there a way to do this in node, if yes what's the logic for it?

**I have an idea how could this be done:**

- Use an identifier markup for node in the HTML file like: `<node>code</node>`
- Load & Parse HTML file in Node
- Grab node markup from the HTML file and run it

But I'm not sure if this is the best way or even if it works :)

Please note I want to learn `node.js`, so express and other libraries and modules are not answers for me, because I want to know the logic of the process.

Comment: Join us in the [node.js chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js) ;)

Comment: This question does not relate to programming embedded systems so I have removed the tag.  see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What your describing / asking for a node.js preprocessor. [It does exist](http://jspp.io/) but it's considered harmful.

A better solution would be to use views used in express. Take a look at the [screencasts](http://expressjs.com/screencasts.html).

If you must do everything from scratch then you can write a micro templating engine.

```
function render(_view, data) {
    var view = render.views[view];
    for (var key in data) {
        var value = data[key];
        view.replace("{{" + key + "}}", value);
    }
    return view;
}

render.views = {
    "someView": "<p>{{foo}}</p>"
};

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end(render("someView", {
        "foo": "bar" 
    }));
});
```

There are good reasons why mixing php/asp/js code directly with HTML is bad. It does not promote seperation of concerns and leads to spaghetti code. The standard method these days is templating engines like the one above.

Want to learn more about micro templating? [Read the article by J. Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Comment: Hi @Raynos could you explain me how can I execute a node.js command from an `.html` file with this templating engine? As I understand this is just changes the foo to bar? or I'm missunderstood something again?

Comment: @CIRK use a bigger templating engine. Mustache, EJS, Jade, jQuery templ, etc. Take a look at the [express screencasts](http://expressjs.com/screencasts.html) and whilst your at it use express, it has a great view engine

Comment: Hello. 2 of 3 links are broken. I don't know if they can be fixed, but I'd love to access those materials :)

Answer (score 6):

You can try using JooDee, a node webserver which allows you to embed serverside javascript in your web pages.  If you are familiar with Node and PHP/ASP, it is a breeze to create pages.  Here's a sample of what a page looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<:  //server side code in here
    var os = require('os');
    var hostname = os.hostname();
:>
<body>
    <div>Your hostname is <::hostname:></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using JooDee also lets you expose server javascript vars to the client with no effort by attaching attributes to the 'Client' object server side, and accessing the generated 'Client' object in your client side javascript.

https://github.com/BigIroh/JooDee

Comment: don't use this. It was written by a friend and I in college, before we understood the evils of what we were doing!

Comment: @maco-taco If you do it beautifully, by re-interpreting the html and substituting only the text nodes, then I think it is not so terribly bad.

Answer (score 2):

Use a template engine. From terminal

```
npm install ejs
```

In code:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');

var options = {
  locals: {
    foo: function() { return "bar"; }
  }
};

var template = "<p><%= foo() %></p>";
console.log(ejs.render(template, options));
```